# Скрытые файлов в public laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

Есть папки с изображениями, путь к ним таков "site.com/1/thumbnail.png", проблема в том что число в url это id пользователя и надо сделать так что бы только например админ имел доступ к этим фото, еще одна проблема путь к изображению нежелательно сохранять в базу, middleware и storage писал, ничего не вышло

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: сначала я делал глобальный middleware что бы ограничить доступ к url фото, но так как фото стоит в папке public к нему есть прямой путь, и я так и не понял как мне ограничить доступ к ней, так же пытался через фасад Crypt при добавлении фото шифровать папку и при выводе что бы узнать путь я хотел шифровать данные по которым я шифровал папку, но почему то шифр всегда разный был так и не понял почему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сам нашел решение через storage может поможет кому то

**Функция рендера изображения**

```
    public function getUserPhoto($user, $filename)
{
    $path = storage_path('app/public/uploads/'. $user. '/' . $filename);

    if(!Storage::disk('public')->exists('uploads/'.$user.'/'.$filename)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return response()->file($path);
}
```

**А вот роут**

```
Route::get('/storage/{id}/{filename}', 'UsersController@getUserPhoto')->name('get.user.photo');
```

**Ну и сам рендер на вюхе**

```
<img src="{{ route('get.user.photo', [$user->id, 'thumbnail.jpeg'])}}">
```

Comment: во первых мне надо подгружать аватар только когда открыта страница пользователя, и нет они не общедоступны, к роуту можна применить middleware и он уже по этому пути не пустит непрошеных гостей, например попробуй `Route::get('/storage/{id}/{filename}', 'UsersController@getUserPhoto')->name('get.user.photo')->middleware('auth');` + я сейчас немного изменю описание, нашел более простое решение